# Rosewill RNX-N600UBE Connectivity issue on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zepus on my computer. I have been unable to connect to any wireless network with 17.04, whether from using the live USB during installation or after it has been installed. I experienced.no problems on 16.04. Although Ubuntu can see my network in 17.04, it cannot connect and it says "Disconnected".

EDIT:

I have followed Jeremy31's commands. The Internet seems to work now, and it works quite well. I had problems installing Steam and Chrome from .deb files with the Ubuntu Software program, so that's why I thought the Internet was malfunctioning. Gdebi fixed that issue.

I have entered my wireless-info.txt file to the link below which I received by entering the commands

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24485625/

Output of lsusb:

```
ID 148f:3572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3572 Wireless Adapter
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513). A fix is to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (e. g. with `gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`) and add the following to the file:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Save and exit the text editor, then run:

```
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Some USB devices perform poorly when power management is enabled for wifi, it can be disabled by

```sh
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Comment: Ok I'll try it out in a couple of hours

Comment: Hi Jeremy31, I tried it and I can connect now, but the internet is very slow. I can search on google but it took 10 minutes to open any other page. Is there a setting I can change to fix this? Is there a way to turn on power management for wifi, could turning it off create a problem (as I have done)?

Comment: You can enable power management again with `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 2/wifi.powersave = 3/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: It may help to change the encryption on the wireless router to WPA2 only without standard WPA, WEP, or TKIP enabled

Comment: I'm not sure if I did something wrong but running systemctl restart network-manager.service with "sudo" made it work for me.

Comment: @user1821961 using the command as I typed worked fine for me and it brings up a GUI asking for the password