# Ubuntu 17.04 wireless driver issue

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04, ralink

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and switched to windows because of wireless problems of Ubuntu. After a while, I decided to return Ubuntu, but confronted with the exact same problem. I couldn't figure out why Linux Ubuntu conflicts with RT3290 wireless. After installation of system, wifi was working, but enable wi-fi option and available wireless connections was missing after first restart. I downloaded rt3290 driver from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/pu4rejmmft8z9yr/RT3290_u16_v1.tar.gz) and installed it. This driver seems like solving the problem, I now can connect to wifi, but my connection is still too fragile: it keeps disconnecting often and youtube videos is playing in low quality. Does anyone know permanent solution to this problem? Is there official ticket about this problem?

Comment: Also see [How to install WiFi driver Ralink RT3290?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

Comment: @user68186 I tried those answers but all of them solve problem for a few hours and after that everything return to "normal" and wifi keeps disconnencting

Comment: @user68186 I think there is a problem in kernel built-in wireless drivers

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fixes are in the latest Ubuntu kernels, to install

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
```

Reboot

There have been issues in the past with this chipset and wifi power management but they seem to have been fixed recently

Comment: I installed ubuntu 3 days ago, so it should be updated

Comment: What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: 4.10.0-37-generic

Comment: I would uninstall the module you built and use the kernel module, I think it is named rt2800usb and see https://askubuntu.com/a/910186/300665

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I'm really fed up trying these complicated solutions. None of them is working..

Comment: Try a new install, then use my link https://askubuntu.com/a/910186/300665

Comment: tried your solution, but no result

Comment: the only working solution for now is the link in my post (rt3290 driver). I install it after each startup and can connect to wifi until I shut down computer