# Ubuntu 17.10 Wifi disconnecting - Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.10, ralink

Good evening, I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on an old computer I had laying around to bring it back to life and do some python development on that as I don't want to dual boot my work machine. There is just one major issue, my wireless card (from lspci it says it is a Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI) connects to the network when it first boots but, after a couple of minutes it disconnects from the network. I googled around and found a lot of posts for older versions of Ubuntu but nothing regarding version 17.10 so the fixes that were suggested did not work on my computer. Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/910186/300665 helps any

Comment: It seems to be working after I changed the power settings (even if it is a pci card and not usb). I will update the thread if anything changes!