# How can I stop updating wifi driver in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, updates, internet

My laptop wifi works when I fresh install ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but as soon as I do the update and upgrade commands. After restart the wifi doesn't work.

But I want to update to the latest version of 16.04. But When I update, the wifi signals then are poor and also it won't connect.

How can I achieve this? (Stop updating wifi or any other soulution)

[My Laptop](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b.shtml)

Comment: Are you saying that after you remove the install media and reboot, the wifi works during the first installed session (with your username and all), but fails upon the next reboot?  Or are you saying that wifi works ONLY when using the install media?

Comment: None of those.
When I install ubuntu 16.04, all things including wifi works great, unless until I give the commands
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

after doing this, when I restart the system. Wifi wont connect and will have very low signal strength

Comment: Please edit your questing to include the output of `lshw` - just the part that talks about your wifi hardware.

Comment: See the last 2 commands in my answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/910185/rosewill-rnx-n600ube-connectivity-issue-on-ubuntu-17-04. One of the updates is for network manager and it enables wifi power management by default and causes problems